# PHP undefined index - sortby

Tags: php, mysql

Its basically displaying data from mysql database and using

```
$sortby = $_GET['sort'];
```

And the error I get is

```
Notice: Undefined index: sort in /home/4507408/public_html/list.php on line 8
```

Here is the full code, any ideas? (Line 8 is $sortby = $_GET['sort'];)

Thanks for looking :)

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'CU4507408';
$dbpass = 'adamadam1';
$dbname = 'CU4507408';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Error connecting to        database");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$sortby = $_GET['sort'];
?>
```

Thats at the top of the page

```
<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <th><a href="list.php?sort=name">Product Name:</a></th>
        <th><a href="list.php?sort=price">Price £</a></th>
        <th><a href="list.php?sort=manufacturer">Manufacturer</a></th>
        <th><a href="list.php?sort=rating">Rating</a></th>
        <th><a href="list.php?sort=categoryname">Category</a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT p.productID, p.name, p.price, p.manufacturer, p.rating, c.categoryname FROM product p INNER JOIN category c WHERE p.categoryID=c.categoryID ORDER BY $sortby ASC;";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("failed!");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <tr>

            <td><a href="link.php?productID=<?= $row['productID'] ?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></td>
            <td><?= $row['price'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['manufacturer'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['rating'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['categoryname'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated, instead use mysqli or PDO_MySQL .

Comment: Where do you get the `sort` from? Seems to be not send or defined properly there. Do an `echo $_REQUEST` to see how that looks like. ;)

Comment: When you load page, sort is not defined and this is what spits error.

Do check and create default value. As suggested by hsz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$sortby = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'default_value';
```

Also if you use valriables passed with `$_GET` you have to check if it is not a value that inject something in your query. Good practise is to:

```
$sortbyValues = array('price', 'manufacturer', 'rating', 'categoryname');
$sortby = isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($sortby, $sortbyValues) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'default_value';
```

Comment: @user3181679 If you find my answer correct, remember to accept it with the tick on the left.

Comment: I will do, you answered it that fast that I can't yet haha! I will tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is occurs because your index is not set on configuration file. You can use any of the following options:

```
 @$sortby = $_GET['sort'];

 $sortby = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'default_value';
```

Comment: Did you copy my answer ? ;-)

Comment: I have give both options to use still I can mention  your credit there :)

Comment: However using `@` is not a good practice. You should avoid errors/notices instead of ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code

```
 $sortby = $_GET['sort'];
```

Add this code in top of your code

```
 if (isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        $sortby = $_GET['sort']; 
    }else{  
       /*in case value of $_GET['sort'] is not retrieved, Action can be done for error handling here. */
    }
```

Comment: because of we can define other value if GET is empty